# Does the 2 terabyte limit for MBR apply to a partition or the entire disk?

Tags: mbr

This is really unclear from what I read.
I have a 3TB secondary hard drive, but I want to install Windows 7 on that (for dual boot). I have an old BIOS so UEFI is not an option.
I understand MBR only allows 2TB for boot partitions. So can I create a 2TB partition to install windows on and another 1TB for the rest of the data? All this using MBR?

I haven't tried it yet, because the disk is full of data, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entire disk.

You cant get the full capacity of a larger disk using MBR, the partitioning and does not allow for it.

[More information](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2010/02/18/understanding-the-2-tb-limit-in-windows-storage/)