# ATI Radeon X200, maximum hard disk supported?

Tags: windows-xp

ATI Radeon X200, maximum hard disk supported?

I have an ATI Radeon X200 motherboard, what's the maximum hard disk size it supports?

Comment: AMD and Google don't recognize that model, and believe that it refers to the Xpress 200 Chipset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpress_200 This chipset supports several differant southbridge models, and your question will be in the specs for the RAID controller it implements. You will have to figure out which SB model your motherboard has.

Answer (score 0):

As the X200 was [released in 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpress_200) it would be a safe bet that your motherboard is BIOS rather than UEFI based.

Windows [cannot boot](https://superuser.com/a/1036686/19943) from a GPT partitioned disk under a BIOS system, which means you are limited to less than [2TB for your boot disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1072770/does-the-2-terabyte-limit-for-mbr-apply-to-a-partition-or-the-entire-disk).

I'm not sure if there are other limits at play, but for a single disk system this limit means that anything above 1.5TB is potentially wasted. I believe SATA has always had support for 48-bit addressing so as long as you have a SATA disk then the theoretical hardware disk limit is in the petabyte range.

For multi disk systems I do not believe this should be a problem. You can have a small MBR boot disk and a large GPT partitioned disk for storage. Windows can boot from a small disk, and doesn't need BIOS support in order to use a GPT disk.  My system is old and is currently set up with a 240GB SSD and 3TB HDD.

On a side note: please ditch Windows XP. It is unsupported and potentially insecure and is loosing program support every day. It may have limits I am unaware of due to its age, but as a minimum it appears that XP without any service packs is [limited to 128GB](http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/hard-disk-drives-capacity-limits/6/).